# AngularJS - update a directive outside the view

Tags: angularjs, service, view

I want to update the scope inside a directive that is outside of my main view, here's my code:

> index.html

```
<!-- the directive I want to update -->
<nav sitepicker></nav>

<section id="content-wrapper">
    <!-- main content-->
    <div ui-view></div>
</section>
```

`sitepicker` is essentialy just a dropdown menu that contains some html structure.

> sitepicker.html

```
<span>{{currentWebsite}}</span> <-- this is the one I want to update
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="website in websites">{{website.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and the JS:

```
.controller('sitepicker', function($scope, websiteService) 
    $scope.website = websiteService.currentWebsite; // not updating eventhough I update this in overview.js
});
```

> overview.js

```
.controller('OverviewCtrl', function($scope, websiteService) {
    websiteService.currentWebsite = website; // assume that this value is dynamic
});
```

but `currentWebsite` is not changing. How can I work around this? I want to avoid using `$rootScope` because I know it's bad.

Here's my service:

```
.factory('websiteService', function() {
   var currentWebsite;
    return {
        currentWebsite: currentWebsite
    };
});
```

**Edit:** Adding a watch like this works but i'm not sure if its good

```
.controller('sitepicker', function($scope, websiteService) 
    $scope.$watch(function() {
        $scope.website = websiteService.currentWebsite;
    });
});
```

Comment: Missing the important part...show `websiteService`. If `currentWebsite` is a primitive there is no inheritance of primitiives and using an object will solve problem

Comment: sorry, i updated it. it's really basic, though. check the solution i came up with..i don't like it though

Comment: It's a primitive ... use object in service and update object property...will work fine then. If you do `var a='foo', b=a; a='bar`; then `b` will still be `'foo'`. If do `var a={name:'foo'}, b= a; a.name='bar';` then `b.name` will also be changed

Comment: i'm not sure if i got you.. I understand that the way my variable is defined is primitive but I didn't don't how to solve it

Comment: try .... Service: `currentWebsite:{name:currentWebsite}` ... View: `{{currentWebsite.name}}`

Answer (score 0):

> Solution #1

We can add `$watch` to makes this possible

```
.controller('sitepicker', function($scope, websiteService) 
    $scope.$watch(function(){
        return websiteService.currentWebsite;
    }, function(newValue){
        // Do something with the new value
    });
});
```

> Solution #2

We can also define `websites` in our main controller. Then, we can update it in our `overview` child controller like so:

```
.controller('sitepicker', function($scope, websiteService) 
    $scope.$parent.website = websiteService.currentWebsite;
});
```

*it is important to use `$parent`*

Since we update the controller that wraps up the **whole app**, we will be able to access it from anywhere, any directive, controller, view, etc.